# Apache server does not show up on EC2 IP

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am trying to install apache2 on my EC2 instance.

I did the following steps:
Launched an Ubuntu 16.4 instance with security group details

- http - 80 - anywhere
- https - 443 - anywhere

Once I login to my instance I did

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2
```

when I type

```
service apache2 status
```

it says that Apache is running

I assumed that after this if I go to my public IP address [xxx.xx.xx.xx] I would see the default apache server page.
But I see `This site can't be reached.`

The process seems pretty straightforward, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does  `curl -I http://localhost` return a 200 status?  If yes, I'd check that the host is in a public subnet in your VPC, check if a host-based firewall is blocking the port, etc.

Comment: show us `netstat -plnt`. If there's nothing on port 80 and 443 then your apache config must be lame.

Answer (score 4):

I had this stupid case, it made me reinstall dozens of times.
Maybe my Security groups don't allow https://

Replace https:// with http:// if available.

It will work perfectly.

Comment: I had the same problem with newly EC2 instance.

You should check your both instance's security group protocol configuration and instance's port itself. Both need to be open.